# Why isn't java one of my "open with" options when I am trying to open a .jar file and I already successfully downloaded java?

Tags: java

How do I get java 6 to be one of the options for opening .jar files after I select properties then open with?

Comment: How did you install Java? Is it Oracle (Sun) Java or OpenJDK?

Comment: I have tried both.

Comment: @Braiam Why? The author of this question states he has tried this with the proprietary JDK installed, and with OpenJDK installed.

Comment: @EliahKagan you should read the other questions presented by the same user. He is in a quest of a mayor project,and it is asking piece by piece what he found in the way. This is one of the cases of X and Y situation. Check the [coment below](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339521/why-isnt-java-one-of-my-open-with-options-when-i-am-trying-to-open-a-jar-fil?noredirect=1#comment435685_339525) and the questions made by the same user.

Comment: @Braiam I've upvoted the answer that solved the specific problem here. As you said in that comment, what matters here is the specific problem asked about here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the reason for that is because you've installed the JDK, JRE. And in their original state, they wouldn't be an option to open .jar files. You can do any one of the following:

1. Download an IDE which has Java support, Eclipse, Netbeans and their ilk. This in my opinion is the simplest way to handle it.
2. Export the JDK's path to folder you wish to work in, using the export PATH command as follows:

`export PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH`

For example, on my machine in the relevant folder i gave the following command: `export PATH=$PATH: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin`

Comment: How do I download an IDE?

Comment: The simplest way to download either Eclipse or Netbeans would be via the Ubuntu Software Centre. Install it from there, and the Software Centre does all the work that needs to be done. Clean simple install.

Comment: @Thomas, if this solved your problem mark the answer as accepted,eh? :D

Comment: I didn't use it because this was part of a bigger problem that I solved.

Comment: @Thomas if it solved this specific question, you should mark it as answered. It doesn't matter if the bigger problem isn't solved yet. This one is.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Thomas, below the upvote/downvote option there is an option for that, looks like a tick, clicking on that considers this answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is because by default, the Java `.desktop` files have the line `NoDisplay=true` preventing them from being shown in menus. You could try to:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit`
2. Type in your account password (for admin rights)
3. In a seperate window, navigate to `/usr/share/applications/` with a file manager
4. Find one that is called 'Java Runtime' or similar and click and drag it into 'gedit'
5. Edit the line `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false`

Then try 'Open with...' again

Comment: What separate window?

Comment: @Thomas Open a separate file brower window

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Thomas : click the 'Files' icon in the unity launcher